# mysqlbinlog: unknown option '--ssl'

Tags: mysql, freebsd

I am running FreeBSD 7. running MySQL 5.1.36 from ports.

I am trying to check some data in the MySQL binary log files, and I get the following error:

```
# mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000021
mysqlbinlog: unknown option '--ssl'
```

In addition, I can't even view the help for this command:

```
# mysqlbinlog --help
mysqlbinlog: unknown option '--ssl'
```

Why does `mysqlbinlog` not know about the option `ssl`?

This server was compiled with SSL, and `ssl` is activated in the `my.cnf` configuration file. We use SSL for remote connections, but I am running this command on the local host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into the same problem with MySQL 5.1.41 on Windows.  [The mysqlbinlog program doesn't support the --ssl option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlbinlog.html), but I couldn't figure out where it was reading that option.  Even when I commented out the SSL options under `[mysqld]` in my.ini, mysqlbinlog was still reading that option somewhere.

Eventually I found that my.ini had a `[client]` section that was specifying the --ssl option:

```
[client]
ssl
ssl-ca=C:/certificates/MySQLCerts/ca-cert.pem
port=3306
```

I commented out those ssl options and then mysqlbinlog worked:

```
[client]
#ssl
#ssl-ca=C:/certificates/MySQLCerts/ca-cert.pem
port=3306
```

I did not have to restart MySQL for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for finding the root cause. Too bad that the `[client]` options don't work with `mysqlbinlog`. I need those options for the regular `mysql` commandline tool.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround to this problem, I figured out that I can skip the defaults:

```
mysqlbinlog --no-defaults
```